# How find this limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{a^x-x\ln{a}}{b^x-x\ln{b}}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$

Tags: analysis

Find this limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{a^x-x\ln{a}}{b^x-x\ln{b}}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

I think
$$e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\ln(a^x-x\ln{a})-\ln{(b^x-x\ln{b})}}{x^2}}$$

I can use L'Hôpital's rule can solve it,maybe have other methods,because I found this interesting form
$$\ln{(a^x-x\ln{a})}-\ln{(b^x-x\ln{b})}=\ln{(a^x-\ln{a^x})}-\ln{(b^x-\ln{b^x})}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{a^x-x\ln{a}}{b^x-x\ln{b}}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\exp\left(\frac1{x^2}.\ln\left(\dfrac{a^x-x\ln{a}}{b^x-x\ln{b}}\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\exp\left(\frac1{x^2}.(\ln(a^x-x\ln a)-\ln(b^x-x\ln b))\right)\\
\end{align}$$
Since:
$$a^x=\frac1{0!}x^0\ln^0a+\frac1{1!}x^1\ln^1 a+\frac1{2!}x\ln^2a+\frac1{3!}x^3\ln^3a+O(x^4)=1+x\ln a+x^2/2 \ln^2a+O(x^3)$$
Therefore:
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(a^x-x\ln a)}{x^2}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a^x-x\ln a-1}{x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1+x\ln a+x^2/2 \ln^2a+O(x^3))-x\ln a-1}{x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2/2 \ln^2a+O(x^3)}{x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac12\ln^2a+O(x)=(\ln^2a)/2\\
\end{align}$$
Coming Back:
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{a^x-x\ln{a}}{b^x-x\ln{b}}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\exp\left(\frac1{x^2}.(\ln(a^x-x\ln a)-\ln(b^x-x\ln b))\right)\\
&\large =e^{\frac12\left(\ln^2a-\ln^2b\right)}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

$a^x-x\ln a=\exp x\ln a-x\ln a = 1+\frac{x^2}2\ln^2a+O(x^3)$, so raise that to the $1/x^2$ power and you get $\exp((\ln^2a)/2)=a^{(\ln a)/2}$